# How to custom navigation menus and navigation bar in Oracle apex5.1

Tags: drop-down-menu, uinavigationbar, oracle-apex

I want to add some components to my navigation menu (user picture, name, search field), and navigation bar(dropdown menu with user informations), to get like this result.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The User Picture and menu here is the how-to (I'm not going to type it or copy/paste since this exact question has been answered somewhere else):

[Apex Profile Menu](http://allipierreapex.blogspot.ca/2017/05/apex-builder-profil-menu.html)

The search you did not specify exactly what you want to search on but to add an object to the menu panel here is the how-to (I'm not going to type it or copy/paste since this exact question has been answered somewhere else):

[region-in-left-side-navbar-menu](http://max-tremblay.blogspot.ca/2016/04/region-in-left-side-navbar-menu.html)

Update 1:
 To add JS or CSS to a page you need to edit the Page Properties (**Ensure the Show-all is selected**) and you will see the fields for JS: File URLs, Function and Global Variable Declaration, Execute when Page Loads and CSS: File URLs, Inline.

Update 2: 
You'd need to search on appropriate APEX view and from there get the right value:
I'd use this query to start what you need:
select APPLICATION_NAME,LIST_NAME,PARENT_ENTRY_TEXT,ENTRY_TEXT,ENTRY_TARGET
  from APEX_APPLICATION_LIST_ENTRIES
 WHERE APPLICATION_NAME = 'Your-App-Name'

Comment: Thank you for your reply GasparYYC, but where should i add the code wrote in the step 5,6 and 8 in my inline dialog, following the first link

Comment: Concerning my second demand (means custom left-side-navbar-menu), i when to use a search bar, to search items in the list of entry, for example: if i have 4 entries: Home, Employees, Departements and Locations, and i tape 'De' i get directly Departements entry.

Comment: See Update 1 for details

Comment: See Update 2 for details on Q2.